# Infinite Graph with Finite Degree

Tags: graphs, connected-components

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with an infinite number of vertices (and edges), and assume it is connected in the sense every $u,v$ have at least one path connecting them. Assume each vertex has a finite degree. My question is: Is it possible for a pair of vertices to exist, such that they will have an infinite number of paths?

Ofcourse, if we allow a path to contain a cycle, the answer is positive. However, I am interested in what happens when we forbid paths that contain cycles.

In other words: Is it possible for a pair of vertices to exist, such that they will have an infinite amount of **simple** paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ gives an example. Take $u=(0,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$. For every $n$ we can construct the path $u = (0,0) \to (n, 0) \to (n, 1) \to (0, 1)=v$ of length $2n+1$. Each of these paths is distinct and contains no cycle.

The same works for any selection of vertices $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Each vertex should have a finite degree. In your example, what is the degree of $(0,0)$? It seems to have an edge $(n,0)$ for any $n$...

Comment: No, it's a grid, every vertex has exactly 4 neighbors. He just made a shortcut in his notation.